# issue in pushing changes to a repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mercurial

Recently I have cloned a `repository` from `code.google.com`, I used [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) plug in. Now I'm facing a problem when trying to `Push` a `change-set` to repository :

```
HTTP ERROR 404: Not Found
```

error comes up. `Error Log` is :

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.CommandJob.execute(CommandJob.java:222)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.JavaHgCommandJob.execute(JavaHgCommandJob.java:78)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgPushPullClient.push(HgPushPullClient.java:85)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgPushPullClient.push(HgPushPullClient.java:46)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.wizards.PushRepoWizard$1PushOperation.run(PushRepoWizard.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.aragost.javahg.commands.ExecutionException: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
at com.aragost.javahg.internals.AbstractCommand.handleReturnCode(AbstractCommand.java:386)
at com.aragost.javahg.internals.OutputChannelInputStream.findNextOutputChannelBlock(OutputChannelInputStream.java:179)
at com.aragost.javahg.internals.OutputChannelInputStream.read(OutputChannelInputStream.java:119)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:193)
at com.aragost.javahg.internals.PullPushHelper.parseStream(PullPushHelper.java:60)
at com.aragost.javahg.commands.PushCommand.run(PushCommand.java:60)
at com.aragost.javahg.commands.PushCommand.execute(PushCommand.java:87)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgPushPullClient$1.run(HgPushPullClient.java:83)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.HgPushPullClient$1.run(HgPushPullClient.java:1)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.JavaHgCommandJob.doRun(JavaHgCommandJob.java:43)
at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.commands.CommandJob.run(CommandJob.java:92)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I have seen [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497709/mercurial-why-do-i-get-a-404-error-when-pushing-to-a-repository-whose-url-i-can), but found no any solution.
Sometimes on `Eclipse` start up I see message :
[image: Error Message]

Please help me in solving this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

It says you should run `hg debuginstall`. I don't know anything on the subject though it may mean run it at the command prompt.